# Enabling / disabling Feature in custom action

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3.6, wix3.7, wix3.8

I have a small setup project that contains 2 features, both published by default (Level = 1). In certain situations in custom action, I want to unpublish (set Level = 4) one of the features. Custom actions written in C#. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are restrictions on where you can that, see the docs for the Condition table and doing this before CostFinalize:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368014(v=vs.85).aspx

so assuming you have that under control, and you're early in the install then use a Feature condition. You already have a Feature element with level 1 by the sound of it, so add a condition that sets it to 4 when a property is set to something. In your code just set the property, and the level will change at CostFinalize.

Example:

```html
Feature Id="FeatureX" Title="Feature X" Level="1"
   <Condition Level="4">   <![CDATA[PROPVALUE=5]]>   </Condition>
```

Comment: I completely understand the approach logic, what I am missing is code snippet that I can't find, how can I access the feature object and set it to 4

Comment: You don't - you set the property value that's used the Feature condition so that the level becomes 4.  See the snippet I added. Set the property value so that the level becomes 4 when the condition is met.